# How to run the Rescala programs

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and due to some requirements, I need to run the Rescala(reactive Scala) programs which are listed [here](https://github.com/guidosalva/REScala/tree/master/Examples/examples/src/main/scala/examples). For example, to run *clickcounter* application, what should i do? Any inputs would be of great help.

Comment: do you have scala installed? if so try compiling the non REscala `scalac ObserverSwingApp.scala` and `scala ObserverSwingApp`

Comment: I got error like this `ObserverSwingApp.scala:4: error: object swing is not a member of package scala` and I did download scala-swing library and placed it in `/usr/share/java/`, then I got different error.

Comment: Ok, I would suggest to use `simple build tool (SBT)` then, you might need to spend some time but that will work. you need dependency `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.11.0-M7"
` in your sbt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To try on `scala console` ,

- install [sbt](https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/0.13.13/) (simple build tool) - https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/0.13.13/sbt-0.13.13.tgz
- create a empty folder
- create a `build.sbt` file with

// rescala dependency

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("rmgk", "maven")
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("pweisenburger", "maven")

// %% will use the scalaVersion defined for scala
libraryDependencies += "de.tuda.stg" %% "rescala" % "0.19.0"
```

- then goto console just firing `sbt console` command, which will download `rescala` for you

// you will some logs as below

```
sbt console
info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] downloading https://dl.bintray.com/rmgk/maven/de/tuda/stg/rescala_2.11/0.19.0/rescala_2.11-0.19.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] de.tuda.stg#rescala_2.11;0.19.0!rescala_2.11.jar (1301ms)
[info] downloading https://dl.bintray.com/pweisenburger/maven/de/tuda/stg/retypecheck_2.11/0.1.0/retypecheck_2.11-0.1.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] de.tuda.stg#retypecheck_2.11;0.1.0!retypecheck_2.11.jar (751ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalamacros/resetallattrs_2.11/1.0.0/resetallattrs_2.11-1.0.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalamacros#resetallattrs_2.11;1.0.0!resetallattrs_2.11.jar (134ms)
[info] Done updating.
```

- then you can `import rescala._`
- you can then try basic `Singnal` and `Var` examples from here - http://guidosalva.github.io/REScala/manual/#signals-and-vars

//

```
scala> import rescala._
import rescala._

scala> val initialState = Var(28)
initialState: rescala.Var[Int] = <console>(14)

scala> val changeSignal: Signal[Int] = Signal{ initialState() + 1 }
changeSignal: rescala.Signal[Int] = <console>(15)

scala> initialState.now
res1: Int = 28

scala> changeSignal.now
res2: Int = 29
```

Same with your question on how to run the scala clickcounter example. Go inside, either put rescala.jar in your classpath and run it or simply create a `build.sbt` and run it from console.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. After following the steps, I believe that there might be some compatible issue between scala and rescala. I get error for the code `val c = Signal { a() + b() }` 
 error is  `<console>:11: error: not found: value Signal
       val c = Signal { a() }
               ^`

Comment: what version of `scala` do you have?? If you check `https://dl.bintray.com/rmgk/maven/de/tuda/stg/` , you will see rescala is only compiled against `2.11` and `2.12`

Comment: I tried myself, its not working for me either, they don't have `rescala`  for scala 2.10 but sbt is compiled against 2.10. I filed an issue to them - https://github.com/guidosalva/REScala/issues/27

Comment: Hi @stafan, so you have to use `scalaVersion` to be 2.11 or 2.12 explicitly in your sbt. It will work that way, see the updated answer.